# Stripe integration with Meteor-React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, meteor-react

I am trying to integrate [stripe checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/tutorial) onto my site. The normal way to do that would be to paste the widget provided onto the document body, like so:

```
<form action="/your-server-side-code" method="POST">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="pk_test_somestring"
    data-amount="999"
    data-name="Stripe.com"
    data-description="Widget"
    data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
    data-locale="auto"
    data-zip-code="true">
  </script>
</form>
```

**What will be the right way to do the same thing, but using meteor-react instead?**

[This library](https://atmospherejs.com/mrgalaxy/stripe) seems to be the correct thing to look for, but I can't figure out how to use it with the available documentation (it even points to the original stripe-nodejs docs). [This official documentation (custom integration)](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom) seems to offer what I'm looking for as well, but I'm not sure how to use it in the meteor-react context. And then there is [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@benjamincherion/connecting-meteor-react-stripe-checkout-ddecfc06adec) which is probably overly complicated for my use case.

I just need a single button that performs the same function as the original widget provided, so hopefully there is a simple way to do that.

Will really appreciate any help provided!

Comment: @Poh_Zi_How, I understand this was from 3 months ago, but did you get this figured out or are you still looking for help?

Comment: Hi @Casey, I got it figured out but did not post the answer here. I can't recall the exact steps I did to get it to work though, so feel free to post your solution here if you have one :)